# Any other way of using .htaccess on yahoo server

Tags: .htaccess, web-hosting

One of my client has purchased server from yahoo hosting services for a year. I've made a website for him an downloaded a chatting script which i have to integrate into it.
On my chatting script it has more than one .htacccess files and as you already know that yahoo hosting does not allowed any file starting from . so does anyone knows about an alternative way of using .htaccess in yahoo hosting servers.

Comment: In short, no there is no way to get it working without the support of your hosting provider. Their server, their rules. So if you can't work with their rules, use another provider.

Comment: what's in those htaccess files? some stuff can be set from php using the [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

If they will not let you create the file, then no, there is no way to create the file.

Next time, pick hosting services that aren't from a giant faceless conglomerate and that expressly state that they support the thing that you are trying to do.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using hosting from large companies. Just don't use hosting targeted at people with different needs to you.

Comment: At a previous job, it felt like half of the problems our customers had with our products were because of giant companies doing hosting.  Telecoms were the worst, followed by conglomerates.  My opinion of them has been slightly tainted as a result.  I have no doubt that the one server we encountered running DEC OSF/1 is still chugging along today...

Comment: Yeah, hate yahoo hosting, it also does not allow to use some jquery and javascript files.....:(